# How to find worst case in chain matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, algorithms

The question we got was Determine a worst-case parenthesization of the matrix-chain product whose sequence of dimensions is (5, 2, 3, 10, 4, 6, 7, 8). 
 what i dont understand is how do we determine how to place the brackets to get the worst possible case

Comment: Do you know what a "case" is here? I.e. what is being tested for optimality?

Comment: Perhaps what is meant is "worse" or "better" in terms of operation count?  While matrix multiplication is associative (and so the final answer does not depend on the order of "parenthesization"), the operation count will be affected in many cases by the order.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a solution to your particular problem. Does this help you in any way? Do you need further clarification?

Comment: Note that [the number of ways to parenthesize a product of $n+1$ matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190385/in-how-many-different-ways-can-we-fully-parenthesize-the-matrix-product) is the Catalan number $$C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}$$.which is not as big as $n!$ for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: @hardmath Do you know of an efficient way to enumerate these? Maybe this allows deduction of some "canonical" chain for each of them, reducing the effective search space for my little script.

Comment: @AlexR: I know something, but probably need a little time to think the best way to do this.  You alluded in your original answer to the fact that not all the $n!$ choices give different operation counts.  Picking any "last multiplication" point among the matrices decouples the optimization (or "de-optimization" since we're after a worst case count) of the first few products from the last few.  This suggests some sort of procedure (dynamic programming) that works from both ends of the sequence toward the middle, possibly giving us quadratic complexity.

Comment: @hardmath If we could effectively enumerate binary trees with $n$ internal nodes and $n+1$ leaves, we would also have a nice representation. Possibly a recursive approach can help here.

Comment: @AlexR:  I get quadratic space complexity but cubic (in number of factors) time complexity to find the worst case parenthesization.

Comment: @AlexR:  I find that my complexity remarks were anticipated by this [related Question, Matrix Chain Multiplication?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187658/matrix-chain-multiplication), for which the claimed cubic time complexity was never directly supplied.

Answer (score 1):

The cost of a matrix-matrix multiplication of dimensi0ns $a\times b$ multiplied with $b\times c$ is $ac$ elements each computed with $b-1$ additions and $b$ multiplications, i.e. $ac(2b-1)$.

This means $C(a,b,c) = ac(2b-1)$. The parentheses in a chain correspond to the order in wich inner dimensions are removed from the chain by performing such an operation.

For example the chain $(3,4,2,2)$ has two possible orders,
$(3,4,2,2) \to (3,2,2) \to (3,2)$ with cost $C(3,4,2) + C(3,2,2) = 60$
or $(3,4,2,2)\to(3,4,2) \to (3,2)$ with cost $C(4,2,2) + C(3,4,2) = 66$

You can do the same for your chain of $8$ dimensions, i.e. $6$ inner dimensions with $6!$ possibilities (some of them equivalent) or you can try to use your intuition (try to bring up large matrices, i.e. subchains $(a,b)$ with $a,b$ as large as possible) to maximize the number of elementary operations needed.

---

**Solution**
There are $10$ optimal solutions (i.e. orders of multiplication with the maximum operations needed). The total cost is $3285$ and one such sequence is this one:

$$(5,2,3,10,4,6,7,8) \to (5,2,3,10,6,7,8) \to (5,2,3,10,7,8) \to (5,2,3,10,8) \to (5,3,10,8) \to (5,10,8) \to (5,8)$$

Another (probably even more intuitive) soltution with the same cost is this:

$$(5,2,3,10,4,6,7,8) \to (5,3,10,4,6,7,8) \to (5,10,4,6,7,8) \to (5,10,6,7,8) \to (5,10,7,8) \to (5,10,8) \to (5,8)$$

I found these using a small matlab script wich describes the order of operations by a sequence in $[6]\times [5]\times \ldots \times [2] \times \{1\}$ with the $i$-th index giving the number of the inner dimension to remove, $[n]:=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. The above solutions are thus represented as $[4,4,4,1,1,1]$ and $[1,1,2,2,2,1]$ respectively.

```
seq = [5 2 3 10 4 6 7 8];
cost = @(a,b,c)a.*c.*(2*b-1);
[o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6] = ndgrid(1:6,1:5,1:4,1:3,1:2,1);
ops = [o1(:) o2(:) o3(:) o4(:) o5(:) o6(:)];
c = zeros(720,1);
for i=1:720
    s = seq;
    for o=1:6
        c(i) = c(i) + cost(s(ops(i,o)), s(ops(i,o)+1), s(ops(i,o)+2));
        s(ops(i,o)+1) = [];
    end
end
optops = ops(c == max(c),:);
```

Comment: cool but how can i represent the following result with brackets, i mean it should look like A(B(CD)(EF)) or something like that

Comment: First write down the seven variables next to each other and write their interfacing dimensions in the gaps, like $5 A 2 B 3 \ldots$. Then set the parentheses from inside out grouping those whose dimension is reduced.

Comment: i dont get it dow e start with 5,8 and get (ABCDEFGH) then go to 5,10,8, but how we would put brackets on that?

Comment: No, the other way around. $_5 A_2 B_3 C_{10} D_4 E_6 F_7 G_8$. First we removed the $2$ first, so $_5 (AB)_3 C_{10} D_4 E_6 F_7 G_8$. Then the $3$, so
$_5 ((AB)C)_{10} D_4 E_6 F_7 G_8$ and so on. Do you get the gist?

Comment: yes thank you i understand

Comment: @user2977404 After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: I would up-vote again for the succint product/dimensions notation, but sadly Math.SE doesn't allow this.